# ggplot2: Change background color of panel and plot independently

Tags: r, ggplot2

I like to change the background color of the plot window independently of the background color of the outer border. I thought I can do this with `panel.background` and `plot.background`.

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=dose, y=len)) + geom_boxplot()
```

This looks good...

```
(p2 <- p + theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = grDevices::rgb(0, 0, 100, 60, maxColorValue = 100))))
```

[image]

And this looks good...

```
(p3 <- p + theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "red")))
```

[image]

But the combination looks strange...

```
p + theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "red"),
          panel.background = element_rect(fill = grDevices::rgb(0, 0, 100, 60, maxColorValue = 100)))
```

[image]

Is there a way to combine p2 and p3, so that the border is red and the plot background is blue?

Comment: I think the issue is that you are passing an alpha value of 60 to `panel.background`. Try `panel.background = element_rect(fill = grDevices::rgb(0, 0, 100, 255, maxColorValue = 100)))` instead. I believe alpha of 255 corresponds to completely opaque.

Comment: alpha cannot be fixed to 100 in my usecase because I create 20 of those plots each with different alpha value and combine those into one grid with `grid.arrange`. So the alpha value is essential for me to create different colors.

Comment: Any other idea to create a color scale for the background of these plots without using `rgb` and different alpha values?

Comment: The `plot.background` is then used to highlight specific subplots

Comment: red + blue = purple. If you use alpha for your blue color, you will see a mix of red and blue, not only blue. For a color gradient, did you look at `colorRampPalette ` ?

Comment: Thanks. Will have a look into it